# Reusing OpenCV C++ files in Android project

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I've written a code using OpenCV in C/C++ to process an image, now I want to port the application to Android (choose file from SD card) then process the image.

Is there an easy way to reuse the code I've written directly in the Android project?

Comment: That depends on what you consider _easy_. Download, install and get familiar with the NDK then give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an OpenCV4Android version that you can use (see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html)).

There are **[samples projects](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html#import-opencv-library-and-samples-to-the-eclipse)** that you can import into Eclipse ADT in the OpenCV4Android package. Try them!

Comment: actually i didn't understood the role of jni files (or how to code them)

Comment: They are necessary to make the link between Java and C++. You might want to have a look at [this](https://coderwall.com/p/nakhrq?i=1&p=1&q=author%3Ajonasvautherin&t%5B%5D=jonasvautherin).